# Bash function has multiple lines of text to write over a jdbc configuration file in a tomcat build script

Tags: bash, tomcat, jdbc, command-line-interface, echo

**The Issue**

How do I get multiple lines of text to write over a file when run from a bash function in .bash_profile?

**Section in question**

Note: This works when run manually at CLI. This does not work when run within the below function.

```
cd /Library/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes;
echo "jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://thisismyurl
        jdbc.username=user
        jdbc.password=password" > "jdbc.properties";
```

**The Bash Function**

```
function build()
{
        cwd=$(pwd);
        SECONDS=0;
        sudo -l;
        /Library/Tomcat/bin/Shutdown.sh
        cd ~/code/repos/web;
        mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -s ../settings.xml;
        /Library/Tomcat/bin/Startup.sh
        yes | cp -rf ~/code/repos/web/ROOT.war 
        /Library/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war;

        cd /Library/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes;
        echo "jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://thisismyurl
        jdbc.username=user
        jdbc.password=password" > "jdbc.properties";
        cd $cwd;
        echo "--- It took $SECONDS seconds to complete the build ---";
}
```

**Background**

I wrote a function within my .bash_profile to rebuild a web front end and update the jdbc credentials after the build. The build and copy of the war works when the function is called from my .bash_profile. The echo command works if I manually run it from the command line. The echo command does not work when it is called from my .bash_profile. It does not make any changes or throw any errors when run within the function.

Comment: Does the directory `/Library/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes` exist?

Comment: Did you `source ~/.bash_profile` after you edited it?

Comment: "Did you source ~/.bash_profile after you edited it? "


Yes, a number of times for each change. I've restarted my terminal and computer several times since this latest version as well.


"/Library/Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes"


So this does exist. The reason I included the whole script instead of a smaller section on just the echo is because starting tomcat again is what unwraps the new .war file into that ROOT folder. After it is started, the mentioned directory exists. It is not throwing any errors on the cd or echo to that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried:

```
function build()
{
        echo "jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://thisismyurl
        jdbc.username=user
        jdbc.password=password" > "jdbc.properties";
}
```

in a file called something.sh
source ./something.sh
and ran build and that worked successfully.

Comment: Same for me actually. I think codeforester may be onto something. Do I need to delay updates to this file until I am sure that tomcat has unpacked the classes/jdbc.properties file?

Comment: some commands can run in a different process. like in a separate terminal process, so very possible. Your specific situation... I'm not sure, but I know it is possible. Might be worth it to make a while loop and sleep it for a bit until what you need to exist exists.

Comment: I split it into two functions and had the first call this one. That worked! Thank you Thad!